# Why won't the score label go up in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I am trying to make a math quiz game in TKinter for school and when the user gets an answer correct the score label in the top left goes up but it isn't working. Thank you for any help in advance. Also it won't let me post the code because it says it is not indented properly.
https://github.com/wackywackster/wackywackster/commit/5ecfadaa780efc17ca78a4a0349f68bc7e7df295

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Updating `score` will not update label `scores` automatically.  You need to update the text of the label after updating `score`.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is because you don't update the text of the label after changing the score variable. If you use a "normal" python variable, you need to update the tkinter widget manually.

There's 2 options to resolve this.

1. Manually update the tkinter label widget. Put the line below below updates to the `score` variable:

```py
scores.configure(text=score)
```

2. The better option would be to use a tkinter variable instead of a "normal" python variable. Using this method, if you update the tkinter variable (which should be tied to the label widget), whenever you change the variable, the widget tied to it gets updated automagically. [This article](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/control-variables.html) does a good job explaining it. Usage is quite simple.

```py
# score = 0
# on line 4 becomes
score = tk.IntVar() # default value is 0
# remove the global score (line 12)

# score = score + 1 
# on line 16 becomes
score.set(score.get()+1)

# scores = tk.Label(app, text=score)
# on line 62 becomes
scores = tk.Label(app, textvariable=score)
```

All with the proper indentation of course...

Answer (score 0):

> when the user gets an answer correct the score label in the top left
> goes up but it isn't working.

Your code is working, but you still have problems.
Looking at my code.

- In line 10,  the `global score` should put outside of `if/else` block.
- In line 14, I add `scores.configure`. Using f-string format. The
  score will be updated if it is correct.
- In line 24, I added `canvas.create_window`
- In line 28, I commented out `#indicator.config(text="")` in `try_again()` function. So you don't need.
- In line 37, I commented out `try_again`. So you can write in one
  line.
- In line 60, I removed `text=""` in `Label` widget.
- In line 64, I removed `text=score` in in `Label` widget.
- In line 71, you are missing declared variable for
  `canvas.create_window`
- In line 75, I added `canvas.delete(btn_tryagain)`

And you are ready to go.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
from tkinter import *

score = 0
num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]


def submit():
    global SCORE
    
    if entry1.get() == str(resultPLUS()):         
        indicator.config(text=f"Correct!", fg="green", font=("Courier", 18))
        scores.configure(text=f'Score: {score}', font=('helvetica', 18))
        entry1.delete("0", 'end')
        SCORE +=  1
        try_again()
        
    else:
        indicator.config(text=f"Wrong!", fg="red", font=("Courier", 18))
        entry1.delete("0", 'end')
        try_again()
        btn_tryagain = canvas.create_window(400, 550, window=trydagain)


def try_again():
    canvas.delete(btn)
    #indicator.config(text="")
    try_again.num1update = random.choice(num)
    try_again.num2update = random.choice(num)
    question = tk.Label(app, bg='green', text=f"{try_again.num1update}+{try_again.num2update}")
    question.config(font=('helvetica', 40))
    canvas.create_window(400, 300, window=question)


def resultPLUS():
    #try_again
    return try_again.num1update + try_again.num2update


app = Tk()
app.title("Math For Kids")
canvas = Canvas(app, width=800, height=600)
canvas.pack()

title = tk.Label(app, text=f'Math Quiz')
title.config(font=('helvetica', 40))
canvas.create_window(400, 50, window=title)

app.resizable(False, False)
start = tk.Button(text=f'Start', command=try_again, bg='brown', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 15, 'bold'))
btn = canvas.create_window(400, 150, window=start)

entry1 = tk.Entry (app, width=30, font=('helvetica', 20))
canvas.create_window(400, 450, window=entry1)

submit = tk.Button(text=f'Submit', command=submit, bg='brown', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 15, 'bold'))
canvas.create_window(400, 500, window=submit)

indicator = tk.Label(app, width=10)
title.config(font=('helvetica', 40))
canvas.create_window(400, 350, window=indicator)

scores = tk.Label(app)
title.config(font=('helvetica', 30))
canvas.create_window(400, 400, window=scores)


trydagain = tk.Button(text=f'Try Again', command=try_again, bg='brown', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 15, 'bold'))
btn_tryagain = canvas.create_window(400, 550, window=trydagain)
canvas.delete(btn_tryagain)

app.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]